# How to declare a vector in header file and use it in definition file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I have declared a global variable vector in `header.h`:

```cpp
std::vector<int> xLayerZero;
```

However, when I use it in the definition file, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error   LNK2005 "class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > xLayerTwo" (?xLayerTwo@@3V?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@A) already defined
```

I tried using `extern` while declaring. However, I'm getting the same error.

Comment: `I tried using extern while declaring` I doubt that.

Comment: Show us "using extern while declaring". Give us just enough code to reproduce your error, if we copy the code from your question into an online compiler (i.e. a [mre]).

Comment: The error message refers to `xLayerTwo`, not `xLayerZero` and appears to be a global declared in 2 or more places. Is it in a header file you pull in to different cpp files?

Comment: Thing is i have many vectors like this and it's showing the same error for all. Actually the error is because i have 3 files. 1) Header.h 2) Main.cpp 3) Functions.cpp .   I have included "Header.h in both Main.cpp and Functions.cpp. That's why It's causing the error. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer not to use globals at all, but when I do I use a thread-safe singleton approach

Header file :

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>

// https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/thread-safe-initialization-of-a-singleton
static std::vector<int>& get_xLayerZero() 
{
    static std::vector<int> xLayerZero;
    return xLayerZero;
}
```

cpp file

```
int main()
{
    auto layer = get_xLayerZero();
    layer.push_back(42);

    return 0;
}
```

And now you can use get_xLayerZero() in other cpp files as well.

Answer (score 0):

I tried code: std::vector xLayerZero = {1} outside main() in both cpp file and it reproduced the problem. Please check if you have done something like this before . You could refer to the document: [Linker Tools Error LNK2005](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2005?view=msvc-160). For more solutions, please provide a sample.